# Cake PHP - XML Sitemap Folder Issue

Tags: php, xml, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

We are using international SEO strategy,
when the user comes from United States he will be landing on US Webpage    (www.example.com/us-en) and if user is from UK he will he landing on UK webpage (www.example.com/gb-en)

Now we need a upload sitemaps on folder www.example.com/us-en/sitemap.xml
When we try opening this url (www.example.com/us-en/sitemap.xml) it is working fine, but the issue is when we are trying to open (www.example.com/us-en/) it is displaying all the files inside the folder but actually we need to display only webpage and not the files.

I'm redirecting all url first key in particular country
If user is from United state

```
Router::connect(
'/:country',
array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index'),
array(

     'pass' => array('country')

));
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    # Uncomment if you have a .well-known directory in the root folder, e.g. for the Let's Encrypt challenge
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5785
    #RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !server-status
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `/gb-en` works and `/us-en` Does not?

Comment: yes....................

Comment: `/us-en` and `/gb-en` are folders too? Where they are? Add your `htaccess` file to the question please.

Comment: us-en is web page slug and folder, but gb-en is only slug (or web page)

Comment: Could you rename `us-en` folder a different name?

Comment: No because each folder is for particular country

Comment: Do you know any htaccess rule ??

Comment: Or any option in apache conf or app controller or config files

Comment: Add this line to your htaccess and check if it works   `RewriteCond $0 !^us-en/`

Comment: not working????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145143/discussion-between-rayann-nayran-and-daulat).